# Remove invalid characters from JSON to make it valid for jsonlite in R

Tags: json, r

I have tried following ways to remove invalid characters and to allow it to be converted to DF using fromJSON of jsonlite:

```
freshDeskData <- extractHTMLStrip(freshDeskData, asText=TRUE)
    freshDeskData   <- gsub("\r?\n|\r|<.*?>", " ", freshDeskData)
    freshDeskData <- gsub("[\001-\026]*", "", freshDeskData, fixed=TRUE)
    freshDeskData <- iconv(freshDeskData, "UTF-8")
    freshDeskDataToDF <-  jsonlite::fromJSON(paste(readLines(textConnection(freshDeskData)), collapse=""), flatten=TRUE)
    freshDeskDataClean <- do.call(cbind, lapply(freshDeskDataToDF, clean))
    freshDeskDataClean <- data.frame(freshDeskDataClean)
```

But it keeps getting stuck at

```
lexical error:
invalid character in string
```

Problem: There is this one key in JSON/column in DF, that has HTML content which sometimes creates problems. It contains user inserted data and though the HTML from JSON returned from API is valid JSON(can be parsed by JSON editors online), jsonlite somehow doesn't parse it properly and gets stuck.Is there a more proper way to deal with this?

Also, I don't mind completely removing/overriding whatever there is in the value for this particular key `description` that contains HTML content.

Is there a way to do it in R?